# Optimizing the Dig Pow function

Tags: python, algorithm, array, functional-programming, mathematics

I have written a Python function to solve the `Dig Pow` problem, where the goal is to find a number k such that the sum of each digit of n raised to a specific and increasing power equals n * k.

Here is my current code:

```py
def dig_pow(n, p):
    if n != int(n): 
        return -1
    stockn = n
    tab = []
    while n > 0:
        newn = n % 10
        tab.append(newn)
        n //= 10
    tab = tab[::-1]
    tabRes = []
    for i in range(len(tab)):
        tabRes.append(pow(tab[i], i + p))
    sum_pow = sum(tabRes)
    k = sum_pow // stockn 
    if sum_pow % stockn == 0:
        return k
    else:
        return -1
```

I would like to get some suggestions on how to improve code readability, and efficiency. Any other recommendations to optimize the code and make it run faster would also be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any unit tests for this?  I'm not sure from your description what results are expected.

Answer (score 2):

Do not merge this code down to `main`.

---

```
    tabRes = []
```

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you spell it `tab_res`.
I ask that you explain what the variable
is intended to represent, perhaps as a `# comment`.

If there is some reference you are following
for this implementation,
you should cite it.

---

It is unclear what `dig_pow(n, p)` is supposed to return.

> the sum of each digit of n raised to a specific and increasing power equals n * k.

That English sentence *could* be a spec, maybe.
The code seems to implement something else.

---

Absent unit tests or an intelligible specification,
it is unclear whether the OP code accomplishes its design goals.

I would not be willing to delegate or accept
maintenance tasks on this codebase.